# bi-directional one-to-one in hibernate spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
class Transaction implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "transaction")
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", nullable = false)
    private InvoiceDetails invoice;

    // some other columns, getter and setter
}

class InvoiceDetails implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "invoice", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transaction")
    private Transaction transaction;

    // some other column and getter setter
}
```

It get an error while compiling this - `Unknown mappedBy in: com.project.model.Transaction.invoice, referenced property unknown: com.project.model.InvoiceDetails.transaction`

However, when I remove the `mappedBy = "invoice"` from InvoiceDetails, it compiles. But, there is column in transactions table which references InvoiceDetails. There is a column in InvoiceDetails which stores the Id from Transaction.

I haven't tried to get the data yet. I am just seeing the columns in database now.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be of type Transaction and not ExternalPaymentTransaction?

Comment: Yeah. I had changed the name before posting here. Forgot to change that. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have bidirectional relationships in `JPA`, you should only set `mappedBy` in one of the properties. the one without `mappedBy` will have a column with foreign key constraint for the relationship in it's table and the other one will not have any column for that relationship. Because `mappedBy` indicates that this relationship is been handled by the property you specified in the other side of the relationship.

Comment: So when I insert the data, is it suppose to be this way - `transaction.setInvoice(invoice)` ? Do I also need to do the other way - `invoice.SetTransaction(transaction)` ?

Comment: if you put `mappedBy` on `Transaction.invoice`, then you should have `invoice.SetTransaction(transaction)` before saving `invoice`. because in this case, `Hibernate` doesn't care about `Transaction.invoice` value as you specified it's mapped by the other side of the relationship.

Comment: `transaction.setInvoice(invoice);
        invoice.setTransaction(transaction);

        this.transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        this.invoiceDetailRepository.save(invoice);`
I did this and got error: 
`org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`

Comment: if you put `mappedBy` on `Transaction.invoice`, first you should save your `transaction`, then save your `invoice`. because if you try to save `invoice` before saving `transaction`, `Hibernate` finds an `unsaved transient instance` in your invoice.

Comment: so is it transaction.setInvoice and then repository.save(transaction) and then then same for Invoice?

Comment: yes, but you can omit `transaction.setInvoice` as you put your `mappedBy` on `Transaction.invoice`.